# Origin of the word vector

Tags: vectors, terminology, math-history

Lately, I've become interested in the history of vector calculus. The subject is generally considered to have come into existence with the work of Hamilton and Grassmann in the 1840s to 1860s. The Wikipedia article on *vector* even states that Hamilton coined the word vector as meaning the $(i, j, k)$- part of a quaternion (if I understand correctly).

However, in celestial mechanics the term *radius vector* seems to have been in use before that time. See this work from 1823 for example: [link](https://books.google.nl/books?id=wFhOAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA445&lpg=PA445&dq=%22radii%20vectores%22&source=bl&ots=2ZtIigk0L_&sig=LcHRa4K_gBzPXHe-T_BdyWc7Z38&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitzqTHzqPbAhXCAewKHb3VBnsQ6AEIXzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22radii%20vectores%22&f=false). The author probably didn't mean a vector the modern sense of the word. Woodhouse speaks of *radii vectores* being distances set out from a certain center of force.

My question is: who really coined the word vector (in mathematics or mechanics) for the first time? And how is this older sense of the word vector related to the modern concept, if at all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why does math.stackexchange have a history tag, then?

Comment: See [vector : etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vector#Etymology).

Comment: See [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics: Vector](http://jeff560.tripod.com/v.html): "The word VECTOR (which derives from the Latin *vehĕre* to carry) was first a technical term in astronomical geometry. The OED’s earliest entry is from a technical dictionary of 1704: J. Harris Lexicon Technicum I. s.v., "A Line supposed to be drawn from any Planet moving round a Center, or the Focus of an Ellipsis, to that Center or Focus, is by some Writers of the New Astronomy, called the Vector; because 'tis that Line by which the Planet seems to be carried round its Center." 1/2

Comment: Actually, the name of the tag is `math-history` not just `history`. And the tag info contains the sentence “Consider if History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange is a better place to ask your question.” Besides, asking, for instance, how Gauss proved a certain theorem is perhaps more appropriate here rather than [there](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "Vector usually appeared in the phrase radius vector. The French term was rayon vecteur and can be found in e.g. Laplace’s *Traité de mécanique céleste*. The term rayon vecteur is used in a non-astronomical context by Monge "Application de l'Analyse à la Géométrie" (1807). On p. 24 he writes, "on nomme la droite r le RAYON VECTEUR du point, et l'origine des  coordonnées devient un pôle, d'où partent les rayons vecteurs des différens points de l'espace."2/2

Comment: Thank you Mauro!

Comment: A very similar question is [MSE 2894159](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2894159).